# Session error in Teradata Fastload Script

Tags: teradata

My Fastload script is scheduled to run every week and when it starts the script failed because of the insufficient number of sessions every week. but, when I restart the script manually then it executed with no session error.

I don't what causes it to fail every week with the same reason of insufficient session. Can anyone let me know what all may be the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check for:
1. Schedule job connection string, if it point to one Teradata Node (I.P) address. Sometimes based on the concurrent session you exceed PE session limit (120 session). Try using DNS/VIP to achive better load balancing
2. Number of Unilities running on system during schedule time. If your exceed the limit of threshold use SLEEP and TANACITY to plance your job in queue instead it fails
3. Limit the Fastload session limit using SESSIONS

Thanks!!